# Change the name of a button that is the "ActiveControl" VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a button that has a label and the button executes a vba event after it is clicked. I want to change the label and font color on the button after the event finished. What is the best way to accomplish this? I tried using `Me!ActiveControl.Name` but found that it is Read-only and the name could not be changed using it. I should note that the form executes some sql and returns results. The button that I want to change the label on takes action on each of the records returned from the search/SQL query. I also want to note that the initial label on the button is set by the control source property after the SQL returns results and some of the fields in the results have data.

The relevant code is posted below.

```
Dim ctlLabelName As Control
Set ctlLabelName = Screen.ActiveControl

'A Whole bunch of stuff is here'

MsgBox "Hello" & ctlLabelName & "there", vbOKOnly, "Label Name"        
Me!ReprocessInvoice.Name = "processed"
```

Comment: trying to change the name or the text?  Probably looking for .Text not .Name property

Answer (score 1):

An Access command button has a `Caption` property.  It is the text which is displayed to the user.  Both the text content and color can be altered at runtime.

In this example, the command button is named *cmdTarget* and its caption text is set to *"click me"* in blue at Form Load.  When the button is clicked, the text is changed to *"processed"* in black.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdTarget_Click()
    ' do other stuff here, then change caption and text color ...
    Me.cmdTarget.Caption = "processed"
    Me.cmdTarget.ForeColor = vbBlack
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.cmdTarget.Caption = "click me"
    Me.cmdTarget.ForeColor = vbBlue
End Sub
```

Actually changing the button's *Name*, from *cmdTarget* to something else, must be done from design mode ... you can't do it with the form open in Form View. But I can't think of a good reason to change the button's name from code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code you have?
You should be able to get a handle on that control by using 
`MyFormName.Controls(ActiveControl.Name).SomeProperty`

Comment: Yep, I posted it above.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the name of a control in run-time.